# CDI Weld ignoring exclusions

Tags: java, maven, cdi, weld

I am using Weld SE to use CDI in my application. Since some libraries may have @Inject annotations and and don't want to let Weld scan all the libraries. Therefore I wanted to exclude certain package prefixes in beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <scan>
        <exclude name="com.**" />
        <exclude name="org.**" />
        <exclude name="io.**" />
        <exclude name="groovy.**" />
    </scan>
</beans>
```

but while executing I get the following error:

```
2014-05-26T17:02:49.855 - INFO  - Version                        - WELD-000900: SNAPSHOT
2014-05-26T17:02:50.340 - WARN  - Bootstrap                      - WELD-001208: Error when validating jar:file:/home/trichner/uepaa/uepaa-net/cloud/target/unet-cloud-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml@19 against xsd. cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'deployment'.
2014-05-26T17:02:50.408 - INFO  - Bootstrap                      - WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
2014-05-26T17:02:50.477 - WARN  - Interceptor                    - WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2014-05-26T17:02:50.477 - WARN  - Interceptor                    - WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2014-05-26T17:02:51.425 - INFO  - Bootstrap                      - WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.junit.WorkflowTestStatement because of underlying class loading error: Type org.junit.runners.model.Statement not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2014-05-26T17:02:51.425 - INFO  - Bootstrap                      - WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.junit.WorkflowTestBase$3 because of underlying class loading error: Type org.junit.rules.MethodRule not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2014-05-26T17:02:51.456 - INFO  - Bootstrap                      - WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.junit.FlowBlockJUnit4ClassRunner because of underlying class loading error: Type org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.

2014-05-26T17:02:58.061 - INFO  - Bootstrap                      - WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from com.google.common.collect.Multimaps$MapMultimap$AsMap because of underlying class loading error: Type [unknown] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.checkForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:51)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer.addClasses(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createClasses(BeanDeployment.java:209)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:351)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:133)
        at ch.uepaa.net.cloud.Main.main(Main.java:31)
    Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:52)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:80)
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:175)
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:97)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:65)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
        at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod(Class.java:952)
        at sun.reflect.generics.scope.ClassScope.computeEnclosingScope(ClassScope.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.getEnclosingScope(AbstractScope.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.findTypeVariable(CoreReflectionFactory.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitTypeVariableSignature(Reifier.java:165)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.TypeVariableSignature.accept(TypeVariableSignature.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:245)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.<init>(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:38)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.of(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:32)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:193)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:154)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:66)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:47)
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:83)
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:80)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
        ... 18 more
```

I'am using following weld version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**How do I prevent Weld from trying to scan those classes, what exactly fails here?**

I checked the format of my beans.xml at least ten times, it should be correct. I want to
exclude all those package prefixes. The project is a maven project with all dependencies in the jar (org.** should prevent weld from scanning itself).

Comment: Which Weld/CDI version?

Comment: Your stack trace seems to imply other issues.  Are you using Arquillian to deploy this app? Are you sure that this is the beans.xml that's ending in your JAR?  How are you bootstrapping this test?

Answer (score 5):

it may be due to not cleaned up classes from an old deploy/compile cycle, e.g. a missing `mvn clean` or old class file removal: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/10600799/10604748